# why my weka doesn't show detailed accuracy by class

Tags: weka

why my weka doesn't show detailed accuracy by class  section in result? how can i change the setting? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statistics output lists `Correlation coefficient` and not `Correctly Classified Instances`, which implies that your class attribute is **numeric** (`RandomForest` can function as a regressor and classifier).

*Per-class statistics* can only be generated for **nominal** class attributes.

If your class attribute is indeed a nominal one, then you have to turn it into a  nominal one, e.g., by using the [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter.

Comment: So if i apply numericToNominal filter, will this affect other attributes?

Comment: If you take a look at the Javadoc that I linked in my answer, you will see that you can specify the range of attributes this filter gets applied to.